# UITableView began with a content offset of -20px in iOS 10 and swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, storyboard

I am making search page using UISearchController and add searchBar as tableHeaderView. But when my results appear in tableview, it began with a content offset of -20px .(I am having Tabbar and pushing this searchVC)
I am using swift 3 and checking the code in iOS 10.

I have tried several things but it didn't work in iOS 10,
like `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

And this is my searchVC

```
self.resultSearchController = (
            {
                let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
                controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
                controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
                controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

                self.searchTable.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

                return controller
        })()
```

Here I attached ScreenShot of issue, my cell gets cut off 20px(ex. VIEW ALL button).

[image: In this picture , Here my cell cuts 20 px]

anyone can help me out of this.

Comment: **insetForSectionAt** use this function for it

Comment: please show me your tableviewController code

Comment: use it in ur tableviewcontroller        **tableview?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)** and 
        **tableview?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)**

Comment: how many section in your tableview

Comment: It depends on search keyword. It's dynamic

Comment: are you Created any TableviewController class or any table view in your view controller

Comment: can you post your complete code of view controller

Comment: @Vivek Shah check your table constraints.

Comment: Table constraints are proper.@TusharSharma

Comment: Hey did you find a solution for this? I'm encountering the same issue with a UIViewController with a UITableView inside